# Geographical distribution of mining power/work

Tags: hashpower, decentralization

Is there any information on how the mining power is distributed geographically? I.e. where the computers are located that do the work.

This is important as **one** measure of centralization of the system, and thus of the trust in the proof-of-work concept.

Of course, there are many different ways to measure centralization, but that's not part of this question.

Thank you!

PS: I'm open to suggestions for better tags of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can find. You could work out the geographic distribution of mining pools based on information provided by [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/pools?timespan=4days), but they receive mining power from pool contributors from around the world, so that wouldn't really give you a complete picture. If a major pool went down (or was blocked off from the rest of the internet) most miners would just switch to another pool.